# Filter results with multiple dropdowns in Google Fusion map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Goal: To be able to search from multiple columns at once in a Google Fusion map.

I've created a map with three dropdowns and a search box (category, state, year, search box). The problem is that each dropdown is currently independent from the others, meaning only one column can be filtered at a time.

I would like to be able to filter from more than one column at a time, by category, state, year, and a search term. For example, I would like to be able to do a search for a "Death of an Innocent" in "California" in "1997" and the term "gun".

Is this possible with Google Fusion maps?

I have limited experience with javascript and would greatly appreciate any help.

The code is below.

```
       <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
              </script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var layer_0;
            var layer_1;
            var layer_2;
            var layer_3;
            function initialize() 

            {
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 

            {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.14756564151492, -97.12306249999999),
                zoom: 4,

                 mapTypeControl: false,
                      panControl: false,
                      zoomControl: true,
                      zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
                      },

                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              });
              layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                query: {
                  select: "col3>>0",
                  from: "1fDfLN7YpE9H7gdGH0ePtJFbwpXy51juTv4-WI24"
                },
                map: map,
                styleId: 2,
                templateId: 2
              });





                          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
                        }



            function changeMap_0() {
              var whereClause;
              var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
              if (searchString != '--Select--') {
                whereClause = "'Type' = '" + searchString + "'";
              }
              layer_0.setOptions({
                query: {
                  select: "col3>>0",
                  from: "1fDfLN7YpE9H7gdGH0ePtJFbwpXy51juTv4-WI24",
                  where: whereClause
                }
              });
            }





            function changeMap_1() {
              var whereClause;
              var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_1').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
              if (searchString != '--Select--') {
                whereClause = "'State' = '" + searchString + "'";
              }
              layer_0.setOptions({
                query: {
                  select: "col3>>0",
                  from: "1fDfLN7YpE9H7gdGH0ePtJFbwpXy51juTv4-WI24",
                  where: whereClause
                }
              });
            }




            function changeMap_2() {
              var whereClause;
              var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_2').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
              if (searchString != '--Select--') {
                whereClause = "'Year' = '" + searchString + "'";
              }
              layer_0.setOptions({
                query: {
                  select: "col3>>0",
                  from: "1fDfLN7YpE9H7gdGH0ePtJFbwpXy51juTv4-WI24",
                  where: whereClause
                }
              });
            }
            function changeMap_3() {
              var whereClause;
              var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_3').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
              if (searchString != '--Select--') {
                whereClause = "'Description' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'";
              }
              layer_0.setOptions({
                query: {
                  select: "col3>>0",
                  from: "1fDfLN7YpE9H7gdGH0ePtJFbwpXy51juTv4-WI24",
                  where: whereClause
                }
              });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
          </script>

<br />



    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">


        <select id="search-string_0" onchange="changeMap_0(this.value);">

        <option value="--Select--">-- Botched Police Raid Category --</option>
          <option value="--Select--">All Botched Police Raids</option>
          <option value="Death of a nonviolent offender.">Death of a nonviolent offender</option>
          <option value="Death of an innocent.">Death of an innocent</option>
          <option value="Death or injury of a police officer.">Death or injury of a police officer</option>

          <option value="Raid on an innocent suspect.">Raid on an innocent suspect</option>
          <option value="Unnecessary raids on doctors and sick people.">Unnecessary raids on doctors and sick people</option>
          <option value="Other examples of paramilitary police excess.">Other examples of paramilitary police excess</option>
        </select>



        <select id="search-string_1" onchange="changeMap_1(this.value);">
         <option value="--Select--">-- By State --</option>
          <option value="--Select--">All States</option>
          <option   value="AL"  >Alabama</option>
        <option   value="AK"  >Alaska</option>
        <option   value="AZ"  >Arizona</option>
        <option   value="AR"  >Arkansas</option>
        <option   value="CA"  >California</option>
        <option   value="CO"  >Colorado</option>
        <option   value="CT"  >Connecticut</option>
        <option   value="DE"  >Delaware</option>
        <option   value="DC"  >District Of Columbia</option>
        <option   value="FL"  >Florida</option>
        <option   value="GA"  >Georgia</option>
        <option   value="HI"  >Hawaii</option>
        <option   value="ID"  >Idaho</option>
        <option   value="IL"  >Illinois</option>
        <option   value="IN"  >Indiana</option>
        <option   value="IA"  >Iowa</option>
        <option   value="KS"  >Kansas</option>
        <option   value="KY"  >Kentucky</option>
        <option   value="LA"  >Louisiana</option>
        <option   value="ME"  >Maine</option>
        <option   value="MD"  >Maryland</option>
        <option   value="MA"  >Massachusetts</option>
        <option   value="MI"  >Michigan</option>
        <option   value="MN"  >Minnesota</option>
        <option   value="MS"  >Mississippi</option>
        <option   value="MO"  >Missouri</option>
        <option   value="MT"  >Montana</option>
        <option   value="NE"  >Nebraska</option>
        <option   value="NV"  >Nevada</option>
        <option   value="NH"  >New Hampshire</option>
        <option   value="NJ"  >New Jersey</option>
        <option   value="NM"  >New Mexico</option>
        <option   value="NY"  >New York</option>
        <option   value="NC"  >North Carolina</option>
        <option   value="ND"  >North Dakota</option>
        <option   value="OH"  >Ohio</option>
        <option   value="OK"  >Oklahoma</option>
        <option   value="OR"  >Oregon</option>
        <option   value="PA"  >Pennsylvania</option>
        <option   value="RI"  >Rhode Island</option>
        <option   value="SC"  >South Carolina</option>
        <option   value="SD"  >South Dakota</option>
        <option   value="TN"  >Tennessee</option>
        <option   value="TX"  >Texas</option>
        <option   value="UT"  >Utah</option>
        <option   value="VT"  >Vermont</option>
        <option   value="VA"  >Virginia</option>
        <option   value="WA"  >Washington</option>
        <option   value="WV"  >West Virginia</option>
        <option   value="WI"  >Wisconsin</option>
        <option   value="WY"  >Wyoming</option>
        </select>


        <select id="search-string_2" onchange="changeMap_2(this.value);">
          <option value="--Select--">-- By Year --</option>
          <option value="--Select--">All Years</option>
         <option   value="2015">2015</option>   
        <option   value="2014">2014</option>
        <option   value="2013">2013</option>
        <option   value="2012">2012</option>
        <option   value="2011">2011</option>
        <option   value="2010">2010</option>
        <option   value="2009">2009</option>
        <option   value="2008">2008</option>
        <option   value="2007">2007</option>
        <option   value="2006">2006</option>
        <option   value="2005">2005</option>
        <option   value="2004">2004</option>
        <option   value="2003">2003</option>
        <option   value="2002">2002</option>
        <option   value="2001">2001</option>
        <option   value="2000">2000</option>
        <option   value="1999">1999</option>
        <option   value="1998">1998</option>
        <option   value="1997">1997</option>
        <option   value="1996">1996</option>
        <option   value="1995">1995</option>
        <option   value="1994">1994</option>
        <option   value="1993">1993</option>
        <option   value="1992">1992</option>
        <option   value="1991">1991</option>
        <option   value="1990">1990</option>
        <option   value="1989">1989</option>
        <option   value="1988">1988</option>
        <option   value="1987">1987</option>
        <option   value="1986">1986</option>
        <option   value="1985">1985</option>
        </select>




        <input type="text" id="search-string_3" placeholder=" Keyword Search">
        <input type="button" onclick="changeMap_3()" value="Search">

    </div>



    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px; line-height: 125%;"></div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that every time you change the value of either one of your input, you are running the function with only that one changed value. You probably need to update your changeMap_1(),changeMap_2() and changeMap_3() make them into one function.

so call it changeMap() and run the following conditions:

```
if(curr_value of search-string_1 != "--Select--") String s1= curr_value of search-string_1;
if(curr_value of search-string_2 != "--Select--") String s2= curr_value of search-string_2;
if(curr_value of search-string_3 != "--Select--") String s3= curr_value of search-string_3;
```

Then perform a search using all three results instead of individual ones. This way, you can keep your previous search category. And instead of 3 onChange function, you need only 1.

Comment: Thanks @larryp, but I can't get this to work. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure it out. If you or anyone else is able to get it to work, I'll send $100 (via paypal) for the trouble.